# Centos Apache VirtualHost setup

Tags: apache, web, centos, virtual-hosts

I am attempting to setup websites on an Apache VirtualHost.

My VirtualHost configuration is included in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.site.com
    ServerAlias test.site.com test.site-london.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site-dev
    <Directory /var/www/site-dev>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

My problem is when I visit **test.site.com** or **test.site-london.com**, I get a **Oops! Google Chrome could not find test.site.com** message.
Instead, the websites are accessible when I utilize the IP address like in the following format: **172.54.88.203/test.site.com**.
A bit more confusingly, test.site.com is what I see if I just typed the IP address into the address bar and push enter.

I tried setting up my **/etc/hosts** file with the following input but it still does not work properly:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       localhost
172.54.88.203   test.site.com   test.site.com
```

Comment: Ensure, the OS running google chrome has also an hosts entry wich points test.site.com to 172.54.88.203

Answer (score 0):

Have you uncommented NameVirtualHost *:80 in httpd.conf?

If this is commented out Virtual Host will not work.

Please check if it is commented and get back to me, it is near the end of the https.conf